# How to join three tables in cakephp,one of them is HABTM table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have three tables :
stores
deliverable_sets
cities

with following relations :

```
//Store 
    public $hasMany = array(
        'DeliverableSet' => array(
            'className' => 'DeliverableSet',
            'foreignKey' => 'store_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

    //DeliverableSet
    public $belongsTo = array(
            'Store' => array(
                'className' => 'Store',
                'foreignKey' => 'store_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            )
        );
//DeliverableSet
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'City' => array(
                'className' => 'City',
                'joinTable' => 'cities_deliverable_sets',
                'foreignKey' => 'deliverable_set_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'city_id',
                'unique' => 'keepExisting',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => '',
                'limit' => '',
                'offset' => '',
                'finderQuery' => '',
            )
        );
```

Now, I  want to fetch list of all the cities assigned to a store through deliveradble_set.

I have tried this code but it does not work.

```
    $data = $this->DeliverableSet->Store->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'deliverable_sets',
            'alias' => 'DeliverableSetJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'DeliverableSetJoin.store_id = Store.id'
            )
        ),

         array(
            'table' => 'cities_deliverable_sets',
            'alias' => 'CityDeliverableSetJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'CityDeliverableSetJoin.deliverable_set_id = DeliverableSetJoin.id'
            ),
            array(
            'table' => 'cities',
            'alias' => 'CityJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'CityDeliverableSetJoin.city_id = CityJoin.id'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Store.id' => 11
    ),
    'fields' => array('DeliverableSetJoin.id', 'Store.id','CityJoin.id'),
    'order' => 'Store.created DESC'
)));
debug($data);exit;
```

Basically I want to run this sql in cakephp's find method :

```
    $set = $this->DeliverableSet->query('select cities_deliverable_sets.city_id  from stores
inner join deliverable_sets on deliverable_sets.store_id = stores.id
inner join cities_deliverable_sets on cities_deliverable_sets.deliverable_set_id = deliverable_sets.id
WHERE stores.id = 11
order by stores.id asc');
```

Comment: What is the Exception being thrown? Especially what is the SQL statement the exception states? Also state the exact CakePHP Version.

Comment: @ele. thank you for your response. After some r&d I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works :

```
    $this->DeliverableSet->Store = -1;
           $data = $this->DeliverableSet->Store->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'deliverable_sets',
            'alias' => 'DeliverableSetJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' =>'DeliverableSetJoin.store_id = Store.id'

        ),

         array(
            'table' => 'cities_deliverable_sets',
            'alias' => 'CityDeliverableSetJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' =>'CityDeliverableSetJoin.deliverable_set_id = DeliverableSetJoin.id'
            ),
            array(
            'table' => 'cities',
            'alias' => 'CityJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' =>'CityDeliverableSetJoin.city_id = CityJoin.id'
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Store.id' => 18
    ),
    'fields' => array('DeliverableSetJoin.id', 'Store.id','CityJoin.id'),
    'order' => 'Store.created DESC'
));
```

Results in following sql :

```
'SELECT `DeliverableSetJoin`.`id`, `Store`.`id`, `CityJoin`.`id` FROM `directorylisting`.`stores` AS `Store` 
INNER JOIN `directorylisting`.`deliverable_sets` AS `DeliverableSetJoin` ON (`DeliverableSetJoin`.`store_id` = `Store`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `directorylisting`.`cities_deliverable_sets` AS `CityDeliverableSetJoin` ON (`CityDeliverableSetJoin`.`deliverable_set_id` = `DeliverableSetJoin`.`id`) INNER JOIN `directorylisting`.`cities` AS `CityJoin` ON (`CityDeliverableSetJoin`.`city_id` = `CityJoin`.`id`)  WHERE `Store`.`id` = 18   ORDER BY `Store`.`created` DESC'
```